# How can I get the values from a dropdown?

Tags: php

Im trying to get some values of my dropdown in php. Its in div, so how can I do that?

```
<div class="ui dropdown selection" tabindex="0" style="right: 120px;">
        <div class="default text" name="dif" id="dif">Difficulty</div>
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="menu" id="difficulty" name="difficulty">
                    <div class="item" value='0' data-value="0">Easy</div>
                    <div class="item" value='1' data-value="1">Normal</div>
                    <div class="item" value='2' data-value="2">Hardcore</div>
                </div>
</div>
```

For example, if user select "Easy", I will get with php the value 0.

I tried:

```
 $difficulty = ($_POST['difficulty']) ? $_POST['difficulty'] : '0';
```

Comment: i think he created dropdown(Select) with div element and get value of selected div

Comment: Ok. I just want to get the values with php, But it is not in select and  option. Its is in div.

Comment: You cannot pull those values using PHP, you must use javascript. If you change it to a SELECT and wrap it in a form you can pull the data using php when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Nicholas Young how can I do that with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them in jQuery or Javascript:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/04/29/using-html5-custom-data-attributes-to-store-data-on-html-elements/

You could store the value in a hidden form and field and use `.submit()`
http://api.jquery.com/submit/
And then check for your post value. Divs do not store values, they are containers so adding 'value=0' will not work. But you can access attributes using JS or jQuery.

Edit: IGNORE BELOW I just saw your edit.

If you're using PHP, you can POST the data to another page.

```
<form action="process.php" method='post'>
<select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then on the process.php page you can access the value  with the superglobal: `$_POST['cars']`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get them from a div with just PHP.  I'm guessing that there is some Javascript that is updating a hidden input somewhere on the page when the user selects an option from this stylized dropdown list.  You'll need to find that hidden input, and that's where your data is coming from when the form is submitted.